# Select From table name obtained dynamically from the query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 Tables

**campaign1 (TABLE)**

```
id    campaign_details 
1     'some detail'
```

**campaign2 (TABLE)**

```
id    campaign_details
 1    'some other detail'
```

**campaign_list (TABLE)**

```
id   campaign_table_name
1    'campaign1'
2    'campaign2'
```

Campaign list table contains the table name of the two tables described above. I want to Select from the Campaign List table and get the record count using the table name i get from this select
For eg.

using select i get campaign1(Table name). Then i run select query on campaign1 to count number of records.

What i'm doing right now is . 
-Select from campign_list
-loop through all campaign_table_names and run select query individually

Is there a way to do this using a single query
something like this

```
select campaign_name,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c.campaign_name) as campcount from campaign_list c
```

**SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b766d/2**

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible inside a single query to build it dynamically but it's possible to cheat. Especially if there are only two linked tables.

I've listed two options

**left outer join both tables**

```
select campaign_name,
       coalesce(c1.campaign_details, c2.campaign_details)
  from campaign_list c
  left join campaign1 c1 using (id)
  left join campaign2 c2 using (id);
```

**union all two different selects**

```
select campaign_name, 
       campaign_details
  from campaign_list c
  join campaign1 c1 using (id)
union all 
select campaign_name,
       campaign_details
  from campaign_list c
  join campaign2 c2 using (id);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67107/3)

Answer (score 0):

Combine your campaign tables to 1 table and add an column named 'type' (int).

campaign_items tables:

```
item_id    item_details          item_type
1          'some detail'         1
2          'some detail'         1
3          'some other detail'   2
4          'some other detail'   2
```

campaign_lists table

```
campaign_id   campaign_name
1             'campaign1'
2             'campaign2'
```

Then you can use the following select statement:

```
SELECT campaign_name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM campaign_items WHERE item_type = campaign_id) as campaign_count
FROM campaign_lists
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, writing took me so long that you got this answered by Colin Raaijmakers already. Well, I'll post my answer anyway in spite of being more or less the same answer. Maybe my elaboration helps you see the problem.

Your problem stems from a bad database design. A database is made to order data and its relations. A CD database holds albums, songs, artists, etc. A business database may hold items, warehouses, sales and so on. Your database holds table names. [... time for thinking :-) ]

(When writing a DBMS you would want to store *table names*, column names, constraints etc., but I guess I am right supposing that you are not writing a new DBMS.)

So create tables that deal with your actual data. E.g.:

- campain_type (id_campain_type, description, ...)
- campain (id_campain, id_campain_type, campain_date, ...)

**campain_type**

```
id_campain_type  description
1                Type A
2                Type B
3                Type C
```

**campain**

```
id_campain  id_campain_type  date
33          1                2015-06-03
85          2                2015-10-23
97          2                2015-12-01
```

**query**

```
select 
  ct.description, 
  (select count(*) from campain c where c.id_campain_type = ct.id_campain_type) as cnt
from campain_type ct;
```

**result**

```
description  cnt
Type A       1
Type B       2
Type C       0
```